# iojs - [TypeError: _runMicrotasks is not a function]

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

Why  is the below code throwing [TypeError: _runMicrotasks is not a function]? I tried in iojs 2.3.4 and 3.0nightly.
I havent tested on Chrome, but its working as expected on FFox.

```
    var p= new Promise(function(res,rej) {
    res(true);
    });

    p.then(Promise.reject)
    .then(null,function(e){console.log(e);} );
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug, you should report it at github.

Comment: @Bergi Turns out  Promise.reject is not a static function, so it needs to be binded.  https://github.com/nodejs/io.js/issues/2181

Comment: Oh darn, I should've seen that (got bitten by it already myself). But the error message is *very* confusing indeed.

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, I checked in Chrome and it threw TypeError : undefined is not a function at reject(native).  It has something to with how promises are handled internally in v8 and how nodejs/iojs call the v8.  Basically  v8 is doing `return new undefined ( )` . That explains error in Chrome..  Anyways I stopped investigating this cause its out of my league. (I spent hours reading source codes of v8 and iojs, didnt understand a thing LOL) ... So i guess i should remove this question here?

Comment: Still, the appropriate message would be something like "*`reject` called on something that is not a `Promise` constructor*". Yeah, you probably can delete the question, alternatively I'll answer it.

Comment: @Bergi Looking at https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/src/promise.js?r=18113#134  there isnt any checks being done.  And with all the //TODOs there seems like the implementation is far from complete.    Hmm.. yes that would be nice. But let me first edit the question to better fit the .then(Promise.reject) use. So that will be helpful for others too. Will ping you once Im done :)